# How to resolve a Probit regression Error message in R

Tags: r, regression

I am running a regression (Probit) analysis in R, but it keeps returning error like

> Error: unexpected ')'

```
probreg <- glm (
             Adapt ~ Location + Gender + FGM + LO + FT + 
               Edu_level + Edu_level + Edu_level + Edu_level + 
               Credit_Accs + Clim_Info + Ext_Service + HCFI + 
               HCFI3dum + HCFI4dum, 
             data=data,
             family=b"
```

Can I get help on how to resolve this error?

I have tried correcting the script and making sure that the variable description in my attached file (CSV) matches the one in the script am using. Still, it keeps giving me the error. I am expecting to get results on the probit regression am running, basically looking at the marginal effects of the independent variables on the dependent variable.

Comment: "Error: unexpected ')'" means there is a misplaced `)` in your code. From my experience, It is usually a trailing parethesis. Cant tell because you did not include the end of the glm call in the question

Comment: In this case, there appears to be a `)` from the end of the one line of code you did provide, but which can't be seen because of the way you have presented your code.  Formatting is important!  I will edit to make the omission more obvious.